# Convert error when there should be none since class implements required interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, covariance, contravariance

I have an interface as follows:

```
public interface IPageViewModel<T> where T : class
{
    string ViewName { get; set; }
    T SelectedItem { get; set; }
    List<T> ItemsList { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have two classes:

```
internal class TestViewModel : IPageViewModel<INotifyPropertyChanged> //let's skip the fact that T is supposed to be a class while it somehow compiles and works with an interface...

internal class HardwareViewModel : IPageViewModel<Hardware>
```

Where `Hardware` is:

```
public class Hardware : NotificationObject
```

And `NotificationObject` is:

```
public class NotificationObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

And finally, I have a class as follows:

```
internal class NavigationViewModel
{
    public List<IPageViewModel<INotifyPropertyChanged>> PageViewModelsList { get; set; } = new List<IPageViewModel<INotifyPropertyChanged>>();

    public NavigationViewModel()
    {
        PageViewModelsList.Add(new TestViewModel());
        PageViewModelsList.Add(new HardwareViewModel()); //error
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is: while the first line in constructor compiles fine, the second one throws an error: `cannot convert from ViewModels.HardwareViewModel to Helpers.IPageViewModel<System.Component.INotifyPropertyChanged>`. 
But this makes no sense. `Hardware` inherits from `NotificationObject` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so `IPageViewModel<Hardware>` === `IPageViewModel<INotifyPropertyChanged>`. Can anyone please explain why there's an error?

Comment: Firstly `class` constraints just constrain `T` to be a reference type, which all interfaces are. Your `IPageViewModel<T>` is invariant in `T` so `IPageViewModel<Hardware>` is not a subtype of `IPageViewModel<INotifyPropertyChanged>`. Given your current definition, you can't make it covariant unless you split it up.

Comment: Well, `IPageViewModel<Hardware>` is not a subtype of `IPageViewModel<NotificationObject>`, in fact they are completely different types that don´t have anything in common. Your `IPageViewModel`-interface needs to be co-variant to allow this, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: @Lee Huh, I always thought `class` constraint forces a reference type. Always good to learn sth new I guess, thanks. 
@HimBromBeere Thanks for the link, I've never really understood the variance topic, so I'm off into some reading, thanks

Comment: @Lee after reading through some variance explanations, are you sure `IPageViewModel<T>` is invariant? From what I've read, it should be contravariant. And by the way, do I understand variance correctly: my solutions to this problem are either removing `<T>` along with `SelectedItem` and `ItemsList` from the interface or changing it into `IPageViewModel<out T>`?

Comment: `out T` would make `IPageViewModel` covariant, not contravariant, however you won't be able to do it due to the setters for the `SelectedItem` and `ItemsList` properties. If you remove the setters and change the type of `ItemsList` to `IEnumerable<T>` (or some other covariant collection like `IReadOnlyList<T>`) then you can make `IPageViewModel` covariant.

Comment: When I said contravariant instead of invariant, I was referring to `IPageViewModel<T>`, not to `IPageViewModel<out T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I've realized the topic causing these problems here is called 'variance'. So after reading a bit about it I decided to go with this solution:

```
public interface IPageViewModel
{
    string ViewName { get; set; }
}
```

But if someone wanted to keep these fields and keep their interfaces covariant, it'd have to look something like this:

```
public interface IPageViewModel<out T> where T : class
{
    string ViewName { get; set; }
    T SelectedItem { get; }
    IEnumerable<T> ItemsList { get; }
}
```